# How to implement multiple "tag" association to a record in MVC view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

As in "SO Ask Question"

I have two simple entities - Job and Tag.
`A Job can be associated with many Tag names` and a `Tag name can be given to many Job(s)`

I have set this up with the code below and I can do CRUD within MVC framework using EF6.

```
BaseClass has an ID property

public class Job: BaseClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
}

public class Tag: BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public virtual List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class JobTagNames :BaseClass
{
    public int JobId{get;set;}
    public int TagId{get;set;}
    public virtual Job Job{get;set;}
    public virtual Tag Tag{get;set;}
}
```

I would like to implement an SO like solution for Job entry. i.e. "Ask question" view here (in the below screenshot) is very intuitive and when entering Tags for a question, it subtly pops up the choices available with  count of questions associated with each tag, I am looking for a very similar functionality with the number of jobs associated with each tag choice.

I am not after a complete solution, but pointers/direction is all I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you are looking for jQuery plugin such as [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/). Check the examples, especially Tagging and Remote Source - Github. There are other plugins but if selectize can't help, probably you will need to do it yourself. It is not clear from question, but I suppose that you know how to calculate counts per tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this S.O. meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102510/can-i-use-the-tag-textbox-script) it references that their input box was inspired by [this plug in](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) but ultimately was custom built to suit their needs.